# PHP data processing not outputting

Tags: php, path, echo, fread

Hi I am trying to get this external text file to print inside my php document. The code looks fine to me however when I echo it does not output anything and I am not sure why this is. Can anybody help me out as I am new to this.

```
$location = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHPLabs/branches.txt';
$fp = fopen($location, 'r');
if ($fp) {
$readin = fread($fp);
fclose($fp);
} else {
echo 'Can\'t open input.txt';
}
```

Comment: There's no echo or print statement

Comment: And you might consider http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php or just `include($location);`

Comment: @Brian I did have `echo $fp;` inside the code but it would output Resource id #3

Comment: `$fp` is the file pointer. `$readin` will contain your data, but you should check the comment from @AbraCadaver.

Comment: @madoreo fopen returns a file pointer resource. Have you tried inspecting the data you just read using fread?

Comment: Thanks I used the `include($location);` function and it outputted the data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to 'echo' but have you checked if the file exists in the first place?

Your code could be written as:

```
$location = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHPLabs/branches.txt';

if (file_exists($location) && $data = file_get_content($location)){
    echo $data;
} else {
  echo 'File not found';
}
```

---

```
if (file_exists($location) && $file = fopen($location, 'r')){
    $file_content = fread($file, filesize($location));
    fclose($file);
} esle {
    echo 'File not found';
}
```

See here for more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: Im trying to check that the call to `fopen` and `fclose` works

Comment: fread takes two arguments: the file handle and the length. you need to do something like this: $file_content = fread(fopen($location, 'r'), filesize($location));